# Rails Ajax - render different partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to submit a post via Ajax call and make the post disappear from the page. I can't figure out how to wire it up all together. I have a page with the list of pending approvals and after I click on 'Approve' I want the post to disappear (I think I need to re-render all pending approval posts). Here's my code:

static/_pending_approval.html.erb

```
%= link_to 'Approve', approve_post_path(pending_approval), class: 'btn btn-success btn-block', id: "approve_#{pending_approval.id }", remote: true %>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def approve
    authorize @post
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.approved!
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Time entry has been approved' }
        format.js 
      else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
      end
    end
  end
```

And here's my problem. I don't know how to make the post disappear without  full page reload. I think I should re-render the partial `'static/_pending_approval'` that I have defined in 'static/_admin.html.erb' that renders the list of posts. It looks like this:

'static/_admin.html.erb'

```
<div class="pending-homepage row">
  <h2>Items Pending Your Approval</h2>
  <hr>
  <%= render partial: 'pending_approval', locals: { pending_approvals: @pending_approvals } %>
</div>
```

'static/_pending_approval.html.erb'

```
<% pending_approvals.each do |pending_approval| %>
  <div class="homepage-block col-md-3">
    <h4>
      <%= pending_approval.user.full_name %>
    </h4>
    ...
    ...
    ...
<% end %>
```

I have `'posts/approve.js.erb'` file, which looks like this:

```
$('.pending-homepage').html('<%= escape_javascript render ????? %>');
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `$('.pending-homepage').hide()` doesn't work?

Comment: But .pending-homepage is the div in which I render the list of posts and I don't want to hide all of them, I want to hide the one I approved.

Comment: So you could create a div to wrap the `.homepage-block` and add it an identifier, then hide it.

Comment: OK, so I have this: `<div class="pending-homepage row" id="approval_2">` and in approve.js.erb: `$('#approval_<%= @pending_approval.id %>').hide()` but it throws an error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an identifier to the `.homepage-block` div, then hide it.

```
<% pending_approvals.each do |pending_approval| %>
  <div class="homepage-block col-md-3 pending-approval-"<%= pending_approval.id %>">
    <h4>
      <%= pending_approval.user.full_name %>
    </h4>
    ...
<% end %>
```

In the js.erb file:

```
$(".pending-approval-"<%= @post.id %>").hide()
```

Comment: Yes, I have `<% pending_approvals.each do |pending_approval| %>
  <div class="homepage-block col-md-3" id="approval_<%= pending_approval.id%>">` and in approve.js.erb: `$('#approval_<%= @pending_approval.id %>').hide()`  but it throws an error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method id' for nil:NilClass)`. `@pending_approvals` is defined in static_controller.rb but `approve,js.erb` is in 'posts/approve.js.erb' so it doesn't know what @pending_approval is.

Comment: Can you define `@pending_approval` in `approve`? or whatever that can have make you have the same values in the div in the view, and in js.erb file?

Comment: Yes, I've just realized that I need @pending_approval also defined in PostsController to have access to it in approve.js.erb. I will give that a shot.

Comment: As you're using @post in approve, I thought maybe that could give you the pending_approval's value, as you're using the js file which responds to the approve method there you could see if it's posible to return an instance variable containting the pending_approval's id.

Comment: Yeah, I got this! `$('#approval_<%= @post.id %>').hide()` Thank you ever so much!!!